# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php

I Keep getting the following error and I was wondering on how to fix it.

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types on line 97
```

Its around this area of code listed below. I can list the full code if needed.

**PHP code**

```
$total_rating_points = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if (!empty($total_rating_points) && !empty($total_ratings)){
    $avg = (round($total_rating_points / $total_ratings,1));
    $votes = $total_ratings;
    echo $avg . "/10  (" . $votes . " votes cast)";
} else {
    echo '(no votes cast)';
}
```

Here is Line 97

```
$avg = (round($total_rating_points / $total_ratings,1));
```

Here is the full code.

```
function getRatingText(){
    $dbc = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");

    $page = '3';

    $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM articles_grades 
             WHERE users_articles_id = '$page'";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql1);

    if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql1)) {
            print mysqli_error($dbc);
            return;
    }

    $total_ratings = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM grades 
             JOIN articles_grades ON grades.id = articles_grades.grade_id
             WHERE articles_grades.users_articles_id = '$page'";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql2);

    if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2)) {
            print mysqli_error($dbc);
            return;
    }

    $total_rating_points = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if (!empty($total_rating_points) && !empty($total_ratings)){
        $avg = (round($total_rating_points / $total_ratings,1));
        $votes = $total_ratings;
        echo $avg . "/10  (" . $votes . " votes cast)";
    } else {
        echo '(no votes cast)';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

`$total_rating_points` is an array.  you cannot divide it by a number.

Comment: how do I fix this because I need to divide $total_rating_points / $total_ratings

Comment: $total_ratings[0] / $total_rating_points[0].  You might also want to check if Count(*) is the correct aggregation function for both queries.

Answer (score 4):

(edited since the MySQL query was added to the question)

You've used `mysql_fetch_array` to get your result from MySQL, as the name suggests this returns an array.  You can't do math like that on arrays.

You want to change your MySQL query to this:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count
         FROM articles_grades 
         WHERE users_articles_id = '$page'";
```

Change your mysql_fetch_array code to this:

```
 $total_rating_points = mysql_result($result, 0, "count");
```

That will return the actual number, which you can then use for math.  Change both of your queries to this format and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

That's usually caused when the type of one of your variables is something you're not expecting it to be.

```
$x = "8";
$y = 4;
$x / $y;   // this is OK, PHP converts "8" to 8

$x = new FooObject();
$y = 4;
$x / $y;   // PHP says "wtfmate??"
```

<strike>Dump out the variables `$total_rating_points` and `$total_ratings`:</strike>

```
var_dump($total_rating_points);
var_dump($total_ratings);
```

.. then work backwards through your code (checking [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) if required) to find where it went awry.

Edit: duhhh.. I just looked at your code again and saw the issue. The `$total_rating_points` is an array, and this is the cause of the problem. How do you divide an array by a number? Answer: you can't.

Do you want to divide each of the members of the array by `$total_ratings`? eg:

```
// input: [2, 4, 6, 16] / 2
// output: [1, 2, 3, 8]
function divideArrayMembers($arr, $denominator) {
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $ret[$key] = $val / $denominator;
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

...or do you want to divide the total?

```
input: [2, 4, 6, 16] / 2
output: 14  // (2 + 4 + 6 + 16) / 2

function divideTotal($arr, $denominator) {
    return array_sum($arr) / $denominator.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_sum()` on `$total_rating_points` and `$total_ratings`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_REQUEST['cityCode'] != ''){ 
    $_SESSION['Cri_locations'] = $_REQUEST["s"];
    $_SESSION['Cri_DateFrom'] = $_REQUEST["startDate"];
    $_SESSION['Cri_DateTo'] = $_REQUEST["endDate"];
    $what_to_search_id =str_replace("AREA-","",$_REQUEST["cityCode"]);
    $total_adults =0;
    $total_childs =0;
    $child_ages =0;
    $no_of_room =0;

    for($i=1;$i<=$_REQUEST["Cri_noofRooms"];$i++){ 
        $check_adults =$_REQUEST['adults-r'.$i.''];
        if($check_adults>0){
          $adults =$_REQUEST['adults-r'.$i.''];
          $childs =$_REQUEST['childs-r'.$i.''];
          $childAge =$_REQUEST['childAge-r'.$i.''];
          $packs_arr[] =array('adults'=>$adults,'childs'=>$childs,'childAge'=>$childAge);
          $total_adults =$total_adults+$adults;
          $total_childs =$total_childs+$childs;
          $child_ages =$child_ages+$childAge;//error accours here pls help 
          $no_of_room =$no_of_room+1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types (its coming like that)