# PHP - Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php

I keep getting the following error and I was wondering on how to fix?

This is the second time I got this error I fixed it the first time but for some reason I cant fix it the second time.

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types on line 103
```

Here is line 103.

```
$avg = (round($total_rating_points / $total_ratings,1));
```

Here is the full code below.

```
function getRatingText(){
    $dbc = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");

    $page = '3';

    $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(users_articles_id) 
             FROM articles_grades 
             WHERE users_articles_id = '$page'";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql1);

    if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql1)) {
            print mysqli_error($dbc);
            return;
    }

    $total_ratings = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $sql2 = "SELECT grade_points 
             FROM grades 
             JOIN articles_grades ON grades.id = articles_grades.grade_id
             WHERE articles_grades.users_articles_id = '$page'";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2);

    if (!mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2)) {
            print mysqli_error($dbc);
            return;
    }

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $trp[] = $row[0];
    }

    $total_rating_points = array_sum($trp);

    if (!empty($total_rating_points) && !empty($total_ratings)){
        $avg = (round($total_rating_points / $total_ratings,1));
        $votes = $total_ratings;
        echo $avg . "/10  (" . $votes . " votes cast)";
    } else {
        echo '(no votes cast)';
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I just solved it thanks everyone!

Comment: Forgot the password to your previous account? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077618/php-fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types and http://stackoverflow.com/users/252134/technut

Answer (score 61):

`$total_ratings` is an array, which you can't use for a division.

From above:

```
$total_ratings = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Answer (score 6):

`$total_ratings` is an array.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error with the following code:-

```
foreach($myvar as $key => $value){
    $query = "SELECT stuff
            FROM table
            WHERE col1 = '$criteria1'
            AND col2 = '$criteria2'";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Could not execute query - '.mysql_error(). __FILE__. __LINE__. $query);               
    $point_values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $top_five_actions[$key] += $point_values; //<--- Problem Line       
}
```

It turned out that my $point_values variable was occasionally returning false which caused the problem so I fixed it by wrapping it in mysql_num_rows check:-

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $point_values = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $top_five_actions[$key] += $point_values;
}
```

Not sure if this helps though?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do this:

```
$total_rating_count = count($total_rating_count);
if ($total_rating_count > 0) // because you can't divide through zero
   $avg = round($total_rating_points / $total_rating_count, 1);
```