# Why doesn't my shopping cart count products of the same type?

Tags: php

This is the code so far.
I know its not very secure for injections, I'll take care of that later.

but my problem is that my cart adds product but sometimes i get the:

> Unsupported operand types in E:\HostingSpaces\Knoppers1\topjop.nl\wwwroot\portal\core\tj_functions.php on line 358

error and i can't add multiple items of the same type.

`line 358: $_SESSION['cart'][$uid] += 1;//`

Maybe some of you know because other related questions didn't helped me.

```
function toevoegen(){
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    }
    if(isset($_GET['add'])) {
        $info = 'U heeft een product toegevoegd <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; URL=http://topjop.nl/portal/winkelmandje.php">';
        $uid = 0; //update id
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $data){
            if($data[0]==$_GET['add']){
                $uid = $id;//
            }
        }
        if($uid == 0){
            array_push($_SESSION['cart'],array($_GET['add'],1));//
        }else{
            $_SESSION['cart'][$uid] += 1;//
        }
    }
    else {
        $info = '';
    }
    return $info;
}

function winkelmandje(){
    mysql_connect("mysql8.mijnhostingpartner.nl","","");
    mysql_select_db("Knoppers1_portal");
    session_start();
    $mand = '<table id="winkelmandje_tabel"><tr><td>Product</td>
    <td>Stukprijs</td><td>Aantal</td><td>Totaal bedrag</td><td></td></tr>';
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $data){
        $id = $data[0];//
        $value = $data[1];//
        if($value>0){
            $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
            while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $totaal = $get_row['price']*$value;
                $totaalprijs = number_format($totaal,2,',','.');
                $mand .= '<tr><td>'.$get_row['name'].'</td>
                <td>&euro;'.$get_row['price'].'</td><td>'. $value .'</td> <td>&euro;'.$totaalprijs.'</td></tr>';
            }
        }
        else{
        }
    }
    $aantal = '';
    $kosten = '';
    return $mand.'<tr><td><b>Totaal:</b></td><td></td><td><b>'. $aantal .'</b></td><td><b>'. $kosten .'</b></td></tr></table>';
}
toevoegen = ADD<br>
winkelmandje =  SHOPPINGCART
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$_SESSION['cart'][$uid]` is the type of variable that you expect it to be? You [usually get this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108875/php-fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types) if you try and do something like divide an array by an int...

Comment: @Henders so what would the code be after that?

Comment: If you do something like `var_dump($_SESSION['cart'][$uid]);` you should see what that value actually is. It looks as though it is something that you cannot add 1 to (like a boolean/array/etc)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like $_SESSION['cart'][$uid] is an array containing id and value as you read it like that in the follwoing snippet:

```
$id = $data[0];//
$value = $data[1];//
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems $_SESSION['cart'][$uid] is an array. so you can't do +=1

maybe do

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$uid][1] += 1; // increment $value
```

Comment: Why would you assume that we want to add something to index one of an array? Surely this is just risking an 'undefined index notice' unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @Henders
I understand that 

$_SESSION['cart'][$uid][0] => id of product ,
$_SESSION['cart'][$uid][1] => the quantity of product 

if i'm right, $_SESSION['cart'][$uid][1] is initialyse when $uid equal to 0

Comment: Fair enough! I didn't know that `[1]` would always be set :)