# how to divide each element of an array

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYBhd.png)     i need to divide the each rating which is posted by the max_rating which is in another table, how can i do this? i get an error now

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error
>
> Message: Unsupported operand types
>
> Filename: controllers/Performance.php
>
> Line Number: 74

my model

```
public function get_max_rating($kpiid){
    $this->db->select('max_rating');
    $this->db->where_in('id',$kpiid);
    $query = $this->db->get('kpi');
    return $query->row();
}
```

My Controller:
...........

```
public function evaluate($r_id = 0) {
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rating[]', 'Rating', 'Trim|required');
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
$data = ['errors' => validation_errors()];
$this->session->set_flashdata($data);

$data['emp_review'] = $this->performance_model->get_emp_kpi($r_id);
$data['main_view'] = 'performance/evaluate_emp';
$this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
} else {
$rating = $this->input->post('rating');
$comment = $this->input->post('comment');
$kpiid = $this->input->post('kpi_id');
$max_rating = $this->performance_model->get_max_rating($kpiid);
$decimal_rating = $rating / $max_rating->max_rating;
$reviewer = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

$ratingd = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($kpiid); $i++) {
    $ratingd[] = array(
        'rating' => $rating[$i],
        'comment' => $comment[$i],
        'decimal_rating' => $decimal_rating[$i],
        'kpi_id' => $kpiid[$i],
        'reviewer_id' => $reviewer,
        'review_id' => $r_id
    );
}
$this->performance_model->add_reviewer_rating($ratingd);


$data = [
    'final_comment' => $this->input->post('final_comment')
        ];

$this->performance_model->insert_final_comment($r_id, $data);
redirect('performance/display');
}
```

Comment: $rating is array. to produce normalized array `$decimal_rating = array_map(function($x) use($max_rating) { return $x/$max_rating;}, $rating)`

Comment: tried it, if i post a rating of 4 and 3 each is supposed get divided by 5 (max rating) but the output for decimal rating for both is 0.99

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code as text; not as an image. Once done, show us the output of `var_dump($this->input->post('rating));` and also `var_dump($max_rating->max_rating);`. Place these _directly before your division_. I suspect one of the operands is an array, not an integer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2108875/296555

Comment: var_dump($this->input->post('rating));                                                              
   array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "3" }                   var_dump($max_rating->max_rating);  string(1)"5"

Comment: @splash58   now am getting the output which is same as the rating eg if i post rating of 4 the decimal rating goes as 4.00 ? my datatype for decimal_rating is (10,2) is that correct?

Comment: I never worked with floats in db, but it seems correct

Comment: @splash58 $decimal_rating = array_map(function($x)  { return $x/5;}, $rating); works fine when i try  i guess when i use $max_rating its not getting divided

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. For code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the `decimal_rating` inside the `for` loop like this :

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($kpiid); $i++) {
        $ratingd[] = array(
            'rating' => $rating[$i],
            'comment' => $comment[$i],
            'decimal_rating' => $rating[$i] / $max_rating->max_rating,
            'kpi_id' => $kpiid[$i],
            'reviewer_id' => $reviewer,
            'review_id' => $r_id
        );
```