# PHP - Fatal error: Unsupported operand types

Tags: php

I keep getting the following error and I was wondering on how to fix?

```
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www\tuto\core\Controller.php on line 23
```

Here is line 23.

```
$this->vars +=  $key;
```

Here is the full code below.

```
public function set($key,$value=null){

    if(is_array($key)){

        $this->vars +=  $key;

    }else{
        $this->vars[$key]= $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$this->vars`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Unsupported operand types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077618/fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types)

Answer (score 13):

`+` can be used in different ways but to avoid complications, only use it on numeric values.

When you didnt initially set `$this->vars` to be an array, it won't work (thx to deceze);
see http://codepad.viper-7.com/A24zds

Instead try init the array and use  `array_merge`:

```
public function set($key,$value=null){
    if (!is_array($this->vars)) {
        $this->vars = array();
    }

    if(is_array($key)){
        $this->vars = array_merge($this->vars, $key);
    }else{
        $this->vars[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
<?php
$test = null;

$t    = array('test');

//$test += $t prints the fatal here

$test = array('one');

$test += $t;

// will only print '0 => one'
print_r($test);


$test = array_merge($test, $t);

// will print both elements
print_r($test);
```

Comment: *`array_merge` expects argument 1 to be array...* :)

Comment: We cannot tell this for sure but `$this->vars` looks like supposed to be an array according to the question.

Comment: But since the OP is getting the error he's getting, it apparently is *not* an array. So this won't help much. The operation is also not equivalent to the OP's.

Comment: @deceze Good point, you are right there. I guess it's `null` when the OP tries his code, null+array doesn't work either.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is in the error. You are trying to sum two value that has different types. You are summing array with normal value;

```
$this->vars +=  $key;
```

`$key` shouldnt be an array

Or second option;

`$this->vars` should be an array

Answer (score -1):

**PROBLEM YOUR FAILED TO ADDED EQUAL SIGN TO THE VARIABLE WHICH FETCH INFORMATION TO THE DATABASE **

Hell guys i tried to remove PHP - Fatal error: Unsupported operand types this error will occur during us fail to declare the variable correct so you will solve it this error by add the sign "**=**" Example if you try to type like this:

```
$sa="SELECT * FROM `anquiz` WHERE user_id = $a";
$af=mysql_query($sa); 
while($cv-mysql_fetch_array($af)){
    $d1=$cv['id'];
    $d2=$cv['answer'];//student answer
    $d4=$cv['quiz_id'];// quiz id 
    $d5=$cv['user_id'];// user id insert his file
    $d6=$cv['time'];
```

you will get error of fatal unsupported operand by sign **-** on varible that carry the mysql_fetch_array instead of adding **=** Take that example` by adding that sign you will see an error

Comment: If this is an answer it is very confusing. What are you trying to say?

Answer (score -8):

1. $this->vars,
2. this->$vars,
3. $this->$vars.

Only number 1 is correct, 2 & 3 are not

Comment: 3. is also "correct", but has a different meaning than 1. Also, what does this have to do with the question?