# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in updateMax function

Tags: php, html, mysql, function, fatal-error

I am working on an eCommerce website and have ran into an issue while trying to improve it. Currently, I generating my cart id by using a random number. I want to be able generate the cart id by getting the max number and then increasing it by 1. However, I have tired to make this work but I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\finalProject\phpfunctions\functions.php:318 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\finalProject\index.php(41): updateMax(Array) #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\finalProject\phpfunctions\functions.php on line 318
```

This is line giving the error:

```
$newmax = $max + 1;
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
function getMaxCartID($db){
$query = "select MAX(cart_ID) from cart";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$max = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$statement->closeCursor();
return $max;

}

 function updateMax($max){
 $newmax = $max + 1;
 return $newmax;
 }


 $max = getMaxCartID($db);
$cartID = updateMax($max);
$username = "Twili";
$itemid = $_POST['id'];
$quanity = $_POST['q2'];
$name= $_POST['name'];
$price= $_POST['price'];
addToCart($db, $cartID, $username, $itemid, $quanity, $name, $price);
```

Thank you for any help, also I know the getMaxCartID funtion works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Fatal error: Unsupported operand types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154508/php-fatal-error-unsupported-operand-types)

Comment: That's not really helpful in this case...

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd start by checking what `$max` is, obviously it's not a number! (You can use `var_dump` to print its contents.)

However, I can already see the issue:

Looking at this line...

```php
$max = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

...we can see that it is an array, not a single value! I would assume `$max` is `[ [ "MAX(cart_ID)" => 123 ] ]` at this point, instead of `123`, because `fetchAll` fetches all rows, not just one (so you get `[ theRow ]` instead of `theRow`), and `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` says you want each row as associative array, so `theRow` is `[ "MAX(cart_ID)" => 123 ]` instead of `123`.

I guess you want this instead:

```php
$max = $statement->fetchColumn();
```